# Blocking JWT tokens AdonisJS

Tags: jwt, adonis.js

In my application, I am using JWT for authentication on the backend created in Adonis. But, I am facing an issue.

Since, JWT is stateless, it can only be logged out by deleting it from client-side. But, I require a feature in which I am trying to logout a user from server side in a case without client interaction. So, I read a few blogs and found out, the best way to make this happen is black listing the used JWT token.

But, now the issue is that if I am trying to black list, AdonisJS just saves the token, how can I blacklist it? I mean how can I compare the Authorization header that contains the complete JWT and the token that is encoded within it?

Basically how can I generate the JWT from the token column of the record that is saved by AdonisJS?

If any other way is possible please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**
You can simply run `await auth.logout()`. The token will be deleted automatically.

**Long Answer:**
You can define a route e.g. `/user/logout`
`Route.get('/user/logout, 'UsersController.logout')`

Then open the controller and implement the logout method. Just put this in there:
`return await auth.logout()`

This 1LoC will deletes the current token for the corresponding user.
However, you can do this manually:
`await Database.from('api_tokens').where('id', tokenId).delete()`

where `tokenId` is the user's token.